# "You are on your knees"

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I found the following English expression. 
WHy do you say "You are on your knees"? Is it because that your weight is ON your knees?

Comment: Presumably because you're not on your feet.  Or your hands.

Answer (score 1):

In this case 'on' is being used as a preposition. So yes, you're correct in your assumption.

> **on:preposition** - physically in contact with and supported by (a surface).
> "on the table was a water jug"

Arguably, you could re-write the sentence as:

> "You are being supported by your knees."
> or "You are kneeling."

However, depending on the context, this can completely change the meaning of what is being said. English is complicated in this way. Sometimes phrases such as 'on your knees' become colloquially significant or synonyms for verbs. In this case, the phrase, as written, semantically implies submission. That said, a lot depends on the context in which it is written.

For example, these two sentences use the phrase 'on your knees' very differently:

> "When you fall down, you often land on your knees." - here the phrase is used in its literal form.

Or:

> "I will consider clemency in this case, given that you are clearly on your knees." - in this example the phrase is used figuratively, meaning the individual is submissive or in a wretched state.
>
> **on one's knees: phrase of knee** - in a kneeling position.
> on the verge of collapse.
> "when they took over, the newspaper was on its knees"

Hope this helps.